# Как отобразить количество комментариев пользователя?

Tags: php, wordpress

Доброе время суток, имеется страница пользователя и требуется отобразить на ней количество написаных данным пользователем комментариев: подскажите как это сделась.

Извиняюсь за неточности. Движок: wordpress, язык: php;

За время копания в интернете и мудрежа получился код:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id <> 0';
$comment_counts = (array) $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT user_id, COUNT( * ) AS total
        FROM {$wpdb->comments}
        {$where}
        GROUP BY user_id
    ", object);
foreach ( $comment_counts as $count ) {
  $user = get_userdata($count->user_id);
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($count); echo "</pre>";
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($user); echo "</pre>";
  echo 'User ' . $user->display_name . ' comment count is ' . $count->total . '
';
}
?>
```

Но не могу разобратся как убрать "выделенные данные":

Количество коментариев: User Ganzimaro Dragon comment count is 22 **User comment count is 3**

Зарание благодарен.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comments` WHERE `user_id`='$user_id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такая вышла робочая функция)

```
<? function get_site_data(){global $wpdb;
  $where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id <> 0';
  $users = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->users_id");
  $comments = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) FROM $wpdb->comments {$where} GROUP BY user_id");
  echo $comments;}?>
```

Comment: Может быть кто-то будет читать этот вопрос и ответ - никогда так не делайте. На каждое открытие профиля нагружать базу данных с миллионами комментариев подсчетами очень плохое решение. Ведите счетчик для каждого пользователя. Пишу комментарий, потому что вопрос топнули.

Answer (score 2):

В базе данных храните счетчик сообщений пользователя и каждое новое сообщение увеличивайте его на 1.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить точный ответ, вы должны были бы указать язык(я думаю PHP), движок либо фреймворк, и базу данных с которой вы работаете. Исходя из представленных вами данных могу посоветовать вот что:
Сделать запрос к таблице с комментариями, выбрав только те, где ID оставившего коментарий = id текущего пользователя. И подсчитать количество строк, возвращенных запросом.

Comment: Ога, и для каждого пользователя каждый раз подсчет. Правильнее следовать совету @ReinRaus

Comment: По этой [ссылке](http://dreamwar.ru/user.php?id=116036) профиль одного человека в одной игрушке с форумом. Посмотрите на 3 строку снизу «количество постов в форуме».